# Cannot save the cookie from express-session to the Chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, express, web

I develop an app for around two months and I have to deal with a significant problem. This app is a CRUD dashboard that consists of Angular for the FrontEnd part and the ExpressJS (NodeJS) for the BackEnd.
The problem that I write for, refers to the login and session saving mechanism. To login users into the app, I have made a custom mechanism that uses the express-session module to handle and save the sessions.
When I try to login from the Firefox browser or postman the session cookie saved successfully on both apps. On the other hand when I try to login from chrome, opera, brave and edge the cookie cannot been saved. The process of login completed successfully without errors but the cookie doesn’t saved on the client side of these browsers.

I tried to change the cookie’s settings, the CORS policy settings and the session-store’s settings.
Do you know/are you aware of what could be responsible in this case? I have searched on google, YouTube videos and in the documentation of express, express-session and cors but have not found anything relevant that resolves the problem.
To clarify, I write the app in typescript and then with the grunt module it is compiled in JavaScript.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.